# Flutter with Riverpod is stuck in loading state

Tags: flutter, loading, riverpod

I'm coding on Login page with Riverpod, everything go fine but when user is try to login, system is stuck on loading state and didn't send data to data state. I don't know why.

my code is like this: login form -> login controller -> login repository, then send data back to login form and redirect to dashboard.

this code in login page

```
class LoginPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/logo.png",
              width: 80,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: usernameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Email / Username',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  final loginDataValue = ref.watch(loginControllerProvider({
                    "username": usernameController.text,
                    "password": passwordController.text
                  }));

                  loginDataValue.when(
                      data: (userData) {
                        if (userData["isLoggedIn"]) {
                          GoRouter.of(context).goNamed("home");
                        }
                      },
                      error: (e, __) => debugPrint(e.toString()),
                      loading: () => debugPrint("loading"));
                },
                child: const Text("Sign in"),
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 105, 240, 233),
                    primary: Colors.black87,
                    minimumSize: const Size(88, 36),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then, this is controller

```
import 'package:calendar/repositories/login_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class LoginController extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<Map>> {
  LoginController(this._loginRepository,
      {required this.username, required this.password})
      : super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    login(username: username, password: password);
  }
  final LoginRepository _loginRepository;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  Future<void> login(
      {required String username, required String password}) async {
    try {
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
      final suggestions = await _loginRepository.loginUser(
          username: username, password: password);
      state = AsyncValue.data(suggestions);
    } catch (err) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(err);
    }
  }
}

final loginControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<LoginController, AsyncValue<Map>, Map>((ref, data) {
  final loginRepository = ref.watch(loginRepositoryProvider);
  return LoginController(loginRepository,
      username: data["username"], password: data["password"]);
});
```

then, this is repository

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class LoginRepository {
  Future<Map> loginUser(
      {required String username, required String password}) async {
    try {
      return {
        "username": username,
        "token": "tokenfromapi",
        "isLoggedIn": true
      };
    } catch (err) {
      throw AsyncValue.error(err);
    }
  }
}

final loginRepositoryProvider = Provider<LoginRepository>((ref) {
  return LoginRepository();
});
```

can anyone tell me, what is wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks overly complicated, I would simplify a lot. Something like this:

```
final loginControllerProvider = FutureProvider.family<Map, Map>((ref, data) async {
  //TODO call login API
  return {
    "username": data["username"],
    "token": "tokenfromapi",
    "isLoggedIn": true
  };
});
```